# Find all passwords stored in powershell scripts in cleartext with a powershell script export data to csv

Tags: powershell, credentials

How can I modify my script to scan for powershell scripts that are storing passwords in cleartext.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path o:\ -Include *.ps1 -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue.
```

I would like data to export to an excel or csv.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Have a look at the [ask] link. Try to add more 
additional information and remove duplicate text. What have you investigated so far?

Comment: ok edited thank you

Comment: How would you determine the difference between a generic String and a String containing a password?

Comment: What would the algorithm be that determines "this script contains a clear-text password in it"?

Comment: You can search files like this:  `get-childitem -recurse *.ps1 | select-string pattern`.

Comment: as others have mentioned - how do you define "plaintext password" in this situation? [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

There are other specifics you need to determine such as what constitutes a password versus a standard string and avoiding false positives.

However, if you're looking for a specific password credential, such as `pass1234`, within all scripts stored in `C:\Scripts\` you could search for that string specifically using the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) command and export it to `.CSV` file, please see the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts\ -Filter *.ps1 -Recurse | Select-String 'pass1234' | Export-Csv C:\Scripts\Report.csv -NoTypeInformation
```